# Getting a new session in IE using SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer

We are using SHDocVw.InternetExplorer in VB.Net to navigate to a web page and insert the login credentials since we have to log into multiple accounts throughout the day. 
We want to be able to be logged into to multiple accounts in different windows at the same time, but I don't know how to get a new session started.

If I log into account A, and then try to log into account B, it opens a new window but is automatically account A, since the browser remembers being logged in with that session.

Is there a newSession or something similar that I can call that will get around this problem?

Edit: is this something can can be done using the Navigate function by setting a header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SHDovVw and the WebBrowser control are all basically embedded versions of IE. If you log into your site using the control and then visit the site in IE you'll see that you're logged in there, too. There's no way to force one control/instance/tab to use a separate cookie system which is basically what you're trying to do. The only way to control sessions is through QueryStrings which could be made unique to each browser.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info.
I guess I'll just have to see if I can figure out how easy it'll be to use another browser type besides IE from within .NET the same way I can use SHDovVw.